# Хочу использовать метод requests.post(python), но на форме используется ajax

Tags: python, ajax, post, requests

Зашёл на сайт(используя логин и пароль)
[image: поля для заполнения]

Хочу добавить клиента методом POST, но тут используется ajax. После выполнения клиент не появляется.

[image: После изменения каждого окна, происходит ajax запрос]

```
url="https://online.smartlombard.ru/login/auth"

s=requests.Session()

log=s.post(url,data=user,headers=headers)

add_link="https://online.smartlombard.ru/add_client/ajax"


client_info={
    "last_name_client": "Валентин",
    "first_name_client": "Пипеткин",
    "second_name_client": "Родионович",
    "birth_date_client": "14.03.2000",
    "city_client": "Москва",
    "street_client": "Набережная",
    "house_client": 41,
}

s.post(add_link, data=client_info,headers=headers)
```

Как заполнить форму?

Comment: Скопируй запрос как cURL запрос. И зайди на сайт curlconvector. Сайт сам сгенерирует тебе правильное решение на python.

Answer (score 0):

надо было поменять хеадер у запроса к ajax